# how to convert date format range in php

Tags: php, laravel

for ex below I am getting date range from input

22 Mar, 2021 - 22 Apr, 2021, so what my question is , in MySQL 2019-01-30 00:00:00 (created_at), how to set date range search laravel query

Comment: carbon : return $model->where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon::today()->toDateString());

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How are these three dates connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php's native functiion to convert string to date format.

```
$startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('22 Mar, 2021'));//2021-03-22
$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('22 Apr, 2021'));//2021-04-22
```

Now you can perform laravel search query. For example:

```
DB::table('yourTable')
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate, $endDate])
    ->get();
```

[See Document: strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)